# Get values after ajax request in json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, xml

I have a problem to get my json after an ajax request. 
When the user click on the submit button, my ajax request looks if the values are correct. I want to return the wrong field in json format and get back after in a callback function. But I don't know how to do.

This is where I call my ajax :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_button_essai').click(function(){

            $("td").eq(2).css("background-color","red");

            $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback);



        });

    });



</script>
```

And here is my ajax :

```
$array = $_POST["arr"];
$json = json_encode($array);

$tab_erreur=array();

    foreach($array as $ligne)//Boucle de parcours du tableau envoyé (hot)
    {
        foreach ($xml as $table) { // Boucle de parcours de chaque élément <table> (xml)
            foreach ($table as $champs) { // Boucle de parcours de chaque noeud <champs> de l'élément <table> (xml)
                if ($table['nom']=='analyse') // Si on se trouve dans la table correspondante (xml)
                {
                    if ($champs->nom==$ligne[0]) //Si le champs xml est égal au champs hot
                    {   
                        if(($champs->type_entree=='Obligatoire') && ($ligne[1]=='')) //Si l'entrée est obligatoire et qu'il n'y a pas de saisie
                        {
                            $flag = false;

                            array_push($tab_erreur,$ligne[0]);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return json_encode($tab_erreur);
```

And now the callback function :

```
function insert_essai_callback(responseObject,ioArgs)
{
   var jsonobject = eval(responseObject );
   console.log(jsonobject.id_analyse);
}
```

I need someone to help me, please !

Comment: jquery is unable to recognize it as JSON. Add `header('Content-type: application/json');` to your code, or use @PHPWorm 's advice of adding 'json' as last param of your jquery code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the framework you are using, but you use

```
    return json_encode($tab_erreur);
```

Maybe you should just echo it. As I said - depends on the PHP framework.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
  $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback);
```

with

```
 $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback,'json');
```

also confirm about the "Tomasz Struczyński's" answer first